# 'expo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR

Tags: windows, react-native, installation

After installation of expo i got this error when i was checking its version.

i was write.`expo --version` after that it shows that expo is not recogized.

Comment: This neither follows Stack Overflow's Q&A theme, nor is it about programming.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes network connection matters, so make sure connection is good. then

run these commands one by one in cmd.

npm cache clean --force.
npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save.
npm install expo-cli --global.

if you still got the error do this. go to the environment variable, then in the user variable section find Path and press the edit button, you will see a new window, press new and add the following

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm
```